# Get Primary records where N most recent Secondary records match condition

Tags: mysql, max

I want a list of Authors (primary records) whose 2 most recent Books (secondary records) are best sellers.

```
INSERT INTO Authors
    (`author_id`, `author_name`)
VALUES
    (41, 'Heida Palffrey'),
    (42, 'Michael Grist'),
     ...

INSERT INTO Books
    (`book_id`, `author_id`, `book_title`, `published_date`, `best_seller`)
VALUES
(156, 41, 'Red Heat',      '2007-01-21', 'false'),
(161, 41, 'Far From Home', '2003-12-27', 'true'),
(859, 41, 'Storm Warning', '1992-08-19', 'true'),
(914, 41, 'Dead Heat',     '1981-01-04', 'false'),

(780, 42, 'The Last',      '2017-01-31', 'true'),
(198, 42, 'Mr Ruin',       '2016-01-18', 'true'),
(166, 42, 'Mr. Troop Mom', '1982-06-27', 'false'),
(796, 42, 'Ben Bootin',    '1972-12-01', 'false'),

    ...
```

For the above data, I just want author "Michael Grist" whose two most recent books were best sellers.

I have been able to get authors with *consecutive* best sellers, but not authors whose *most recent* two books were best sellers.

```
SELECT t.author_id, a.author_name, t.consecutive, t.best_seller, COUNT(1) consecutive_count
FROM (
  SELECT b.* ,
    @r:= CASE WHEN @g = b.`best_seller` THEN @r ELSE @r + 1 END consecutive,
    @g:= b.`best_seller` g
  FROM books b
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:='true', @r:=0) t1
  ORDER BY author_id, published_date
) t
JOIN `authors` `a` ON (`a`.author_id = t.author_id)
GROUP BY t.author_id,t.consecutive,t.`best_seller`
HAVING consecutive_count >= 2 AND  t.`best_seller` = 'true';
```

For the data in the sqlfiddle below, only Chaddie Dreakin and Michael Grist fit the requirements of two most recent best sellers.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8808649/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 9;

SELECT  a.author_name
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  author_id,
                GROUP_CONCAT(best_seller ORDER BY  published_date DESC) AS bs
            FROM  Books
            GROUP BY  author_id
            HAVING  bs = 'true,true' 
    ) AS x
    JOIN  Authors AS a USING(author_id) ;
```

Notes:

- `9` is based on `true,true` being 9 characters, and that is enough to catch the first two.
- I'm assuming `best_seller` is a `VARCHAR`.
- `ORDER BY  published_date DESC` -- the "latest"
- `HAVING` -- can't use `WHERE` in this situation

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8808649/44

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that works for me

```
SELECT t.author_id, a.author_name, t.consecutive, t.new
FROM (
  SELECT b.* ,
    @n:= CASE WHEN @a = b.`author_id` THEN @n+1  ELSE 1 END new,
    @r:= CASE WHEN @n = 1 THEN 
            CASE WHEN b.`best_seller` = 'true' THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
            END
         ELSE
            CASE WHEN @g = b.`best_seller` THEN @r + 1
             WHEN b.`best_seller` = 'true' THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END
         END consecutive,
    @a:= b.`author_id` a,
    @g:= b.`best_seller` g
  FROM books b
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:='true', @r:=0) t1
  ORDER BY author_id, published_date DESC
) t
JOIN `authors` `a` ON (`a`.author_id = t.author_id)
WHERE `consecutive` = 2 AND  `new` = 2;
```

Happy to select another answer if someone can significantly clean this up.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8808649/39

Answer (score -1):

```
select author_name from 
(
select * from 
(                                      -- emulate row_number()
select ta.*,
if(@typex=ta.author_id, 
@rownum:=@rownum+1, 
@rownum:=1+least(0,@typex:=ta.author_id)) rown 
from Books ta, (select @rownum:=1, @typex:='_') zz
order by author_id, published_date DESC
) yy
where rown < 3                          -- get first 2 records
) zz join authors using(author_id)
group by author_id
having sum(best_seller = 'true') = 2    -- check both are best sellers
;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8808649/43)

Comment: Thank you Akina.  Can you add a bit more prose to explain how it works?

Comment: @ThunderRabbit Look at the most inner query (aliased as `yy`). It emulates `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY author_id ORDER BY published_date DESC)`. It processes records one-by-one in `order by author_id, published_date DESC` order. If `author_id` it the same as in previous record it increases `@rownum` else assign it to 1. Middle subquery abandons the records with numbers of 3 or more. Outer query groups remaining records by `author_name` and filters the records with both `best_seller` fields contained `'true'`.